# How do I properly switch this animation keyframe in a media query?

Tags: css, animation, media-queries, css-animations, keyframe

I have an animation keyframe that I want to adjust within a media query targeting a device's landscape orientation. I've gotten it to switch keyframes when the device is in landscape and the page is refreshed, however I want it to automatically switch keyframes upon orientation change without the need of a page refresh.

**Here is the css**:

```
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 130px, 0px);

  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
}
.animated-object {
  position: relative;
  animation: slide 2s infinite;
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 667px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
  @keyframes slide {
    20% {
      transform: translate3d(0px, 13px, 0px);
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get this keyframe to switch **automatically** upon the device being rotated into landscape rather than needing a refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes on your code. check it here.

**HTML**

```
<div class="animated-object">Animate Object<div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font: 150%/1.5 Arial;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

.animated-object {
  animation: bounce .6s alternate infinite ease-in;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}


@media only screen 
and (min-width : 100px)
and (max-width : 700px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
  @keyframes bounce {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(-200%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
  .animated-object{
    color: green;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**For Demo**
http://codepen.io/l3ikrant/pen/eZNrgK

Answer (score 0):

I've just done something similar to this I basically created `@keyframes slidePortrait` and `@keyframes slideLandscape`

Then used `@media screen and (orientation:landscape)` to call `slideLandscape` and `@media screen and (orientation:portrait)` to call `slidePortrait`